# staging and prod skipped

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

**entire pipeline was run successfully but why staging and prod were skipped ?**
I have completed all the steps in Azure pipelines but it wan't completed staging and prod. I want to know that why those are skipping

[image]
azure-pipelines.yml

```
  branches:
    include:
    - master
pool:
  name: CharanAgentPool
variables:
- name: buildConfiguration
  value: Release
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: ApplicationBuild
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    variables:
    - name: continueOnError
      value: false
    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: restore
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
    - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: '**\*.sln'
        msbuildArgs: /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"
        configuration: release
        clean: true
        restoreNugetPackages: true
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
        ArtifactName: drop
        publishLocation: Container
- stage: Test
  displayName: UnitTest
  jobs:
  - job: Test
    steps:
    - task: VSTest@2
      inputs:
        testSelector: testAssemblies
        testAssemblyVer2: >
          **\*test*.dll

          !**\*TestAdapter.dll

          !**\obj\**
        searchFolder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
- stage: SonarQube
  displayName: StaticCodeAnalysis
  jobs:
  - job: SonarQube
    steps:
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: echo "code analysis"

- stage: deploy_dev
  displayName: ApplicationDeplo
  jobs:
  - job: dev
    steps:
    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      inputs:
        buildType: current
        downloadType: single
        artifactName: drop
        downloadPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
    - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
      inputs:
        ConnectionType: AzureRM
        azureSubscription: '$(connectedservicename)'
        appType: webApp
        WebAppName: '$(app_name)'
        packageForLinux: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/drop/*.zip
- stage: functionaltest_dev
  displayName: FunctionalTest
  jobs:
  - job: FunctionalTesting
    steps:
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: echo "function testing"
- stage: deploy_staging
  displayName: staging
  jobs:
  - job: staging
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['deploy_staging'], 'yes'))
    steps:
    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      inputs:
        buildType: current
        downloadType: single
        artifactName: drop
        downloadPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
    - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
      inputs:
        ConnectionType: AzureRM
        azureSubscription: '$(connectedservicename)'
        appType: webApp
        WebAppName: $(staging_app)
        packageForLinux: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/drop/*.zip
- stage: functionaltest_staging
  displayName: FunctionalTestStaging
  jobs:
  - job: FunctionalTesting
    steps:
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: echo "function testing"
- stage: deploy_prod
  displayName: DeployToProd
  jobs:
  - job: prod
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['deploy_prod'], 'yes'))
    steps:
    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      inputs:
        buildType: current
        downloadType: single
        artifactName: drop
        downloadPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
    - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
      inputs:
        ConnectionType: AzureRM
        azureSubscription: '$(connectedservicename)'
        appType: webApp
        WebAppName: $(prod_app)
        packageForLinux: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/drop/*.zip
- stage: functionaltest_prod
  displayName: FunctionalTestingProd
  jobs:
  - job: FunctionalTesting
    steps:
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: echo "function testing"
```

entire pipeline was run successfully but why staging and prod were skipped ?

Comment: Are they all in the master repo? also you have named some pipelines as deploy to prod, but you are configuring build pipelines not release pipelines so not sure what you expect to happen here, normally you build once and deploy multiple times using release pipelines, more information is needed as to what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I am running them in main branch and all the code was set by default

Answer (score 1):

```
- job: staging
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['deploy_staging'], 'yes'))
```

This chunk of pipeline controlls when job will run. Condition which you set checks if steps before ended succesfully and if variable **deploy_staging** is set to yes.

You never set the variable to yes so this job won't run.

Comment: Where can I set the value for deploy_staging and deloy_prod variables ?

Comment: On the pipeline start you have variables.

Comment: yeah but where and how can i add the values to deploy_prod and deploy_staging ?

Comment: You need to edit azure-pipelines.yml file in repo.